# Convert from one delegate to another. Pseudo cast

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

We are using IoC and have our logging exposed with it. We are using `Common.Logging` and I have written a matching delegate for `Common.Logging.FormatMessageHandler` but I do not know how to convert from our version of that delegate to the one that the `Common.Logging` api is expecting.

This question appears to be similar but I do not understand how to convert from my implemented type to the known type that I want to call.
[Dynamically casting one type of delegate to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589999/dynamically-casting-one-type-of-delegate-to-another)

Here is my delegate signature:

```
public delegate string FormatMessageHandler(string format, params object[] args)
```

Here is Common.Logging's:

```
public delegate string FormatMessageHandler(string format, params object[] args)
```

Same name (not that is matters) and same number of parameters. Both are known at compile time so it should be something obvious but I am not seeing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why are you not using Common.Logging's delegate in the first place if it is exactly the same?

However, a solution to your problem is to either use the dynamic cast explained in the article linked in the question you mentioned, or you do it like this:

```
YourNamespace.FormatMessageHandler yourHandler = ...;
Common.Logging.FormatMessageHandler handler = (f, a) => yourHandler(f, a);
```

**UPDATE:**
According to your comment, you want something like that:

```
public void Error(Action<Your.FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback)
{
    _logger.Error(h => formatMessageCallback((f, a) => h(f, a)));
}
```

This will create a new action with one parameter `h` of type `Common.Logging.FormatMessageHandler` which calls the supplied action `formatMessageCallback` with a new delegate of `Your.FormatMessageHandler` that accepts two parameters `f` and `a`. This new delegate in turn calls `h` with the two supplied parameters.

Comment: Your explain is great and works until I attempt to use the Action<T>. How can I do with with Action?
My method signature:
public void Error(Action<DegreeTree.Domain.Interfaces.FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback)
And the final method to call is:
void Common.Logging.Error(Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback);

Comment: I am not exposing the Common.Logging delegate or any of the API incase we decide to use a different logging framework in the future. If that happens then "all" we have to do is write some code that implements the logging interface that we defined before and wrap the calls to the new logging framework.

Comment: @David: The reason for not using the Logger's delegate is valid, thanks for explaining. Please see the update for a solution to your first comment.

Answer (score 2):

Manually you can do this, but it is as expensive as the reflection involved at conversion.  Once the delegate is converted it behaves basically the same...

```
internal class Program
{
    //An example delegate target
    static void Click(object o, EventArgs e) { }

    //A simple test method
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EventHandler onclick = Click;
        EventHandler<EventArgs> converted;
        if (!TryConvertDelegate(onclick, out converted))
            throw new Exception("failed");
    }

    //The conversion of one delegate type to another
    static bool TryConvertDelegate<TOldType, TNewType>(TOldType oldDelegate, out TNewType newDelegate)
        where TOldType : class, System.ICloneable, System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable
        where TNewType : class, System.ICloneable, System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable
    {
        if (!typeof(Delegate).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TOldType)) || !typeof(Delegate).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TNewType)))
            throw new ArgumentException(); //one of the types is not a delegate

        newDelegate = default(TNewType);
        Delegate handler = oldDelegate as System.Delegate;
        if (handler == null)
            return true; //null in, null out

        Delegate result = null;
        foreach (Delegate d in handler.GetInvocationList())
        {
            object copy = System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(TNewType), d.Target, d.Method, false);
            if (copy == null)
                return false; // one or more can not be converted
            result = System.Delegate.Combine(result, (System.Delegate)copy);
        }
        newDelegate = result as TNewType;
        return (newDelegate != null);
    }
```